# RaycastHit issues with canvas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script gives a message on the console only if the hit gameobject is not in a canvas. When the mouse button is released on a button located inside a canvas, the script doesn't debug anything. How can I fix this?

```
RaycastHit hit;

void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        //RayHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            // do what you want
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean canvas as for UI? If so you just doing it wrong please read [tutorial about UI in Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this to get which UI object is clicked.

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);


        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {
            Debug.Log(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Text>().name);

        }
```

> EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent().name

will return clicked object and

> EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()

will check if an UI object is click or not.